# Can't stub things with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, stub

I have a Rails 4 application, and here is my lib/foobar:

```
jan@rmbp ~/D/r/v/l/foobar> tree
.
├── foo_bar.rb
└── foobar_spec.rb

0 directories, 2 files
```

And the files:

foobar_spec.rb

```
require "spec_helper"

describe "FooBar" do
  subject { FooBar.new }
  its(:foo) { should == "foo"}
  #stubbed version of test crashes
  #FooBar.stub(:foo).and_return("bar")
  #subject { FooBar.new }
  #its(:foo) { should == "bar"}

end
```

foo_bar.rb

```
class FooBar
  def foo
    "foo"
  end
end
```

spec_helper.rb:

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
# commented for zeus two runs bug
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'capybara/rspec'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migrations before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)

RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
  config.include Features::SessionHelpers, type: :feature

  # ## Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr
  config.mock_with :rspec

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = "random"
end
```

The spec passes fine. But when I uncomment this line:

```
# FooBar.stub(:foo).and_return("bar")
```

It fails with:

```
/Users/jan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-mocks-2.14.3/lib/rspec/mocks.rb:26:in `proxy_for': undefined method `proxy_for' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

What is wrong?

EDIT:
Also, I can't seem to be able to use `webmock` either.

```
  stub_request(:post, "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token")
         .with(:body => { "client_id"     => CLIENT_ID,
                         "client_secret" => CLIENT_SECRET,
                         "refresh_token" => refresh_token, }
         ).to_return(:status => 200,
                     :body => File.read("#{$fixtures}/refresh_token.json"))
```

Returns:

> /Users/jan/Documents/ruby/vince.re/lib/youtube/you_tube_test.rb:9:in
>   `block in <top (required)>': undefined method`stub_request' for
>    < Class :0x007f8159bbe7c0> (NoMethodError)

**SOLUTION:**
Thanks to @gotva for telling me about stubs requirement to reside within `it` blocks. Here is my new, fixed webmock test, and it works great:

```
  context "when token is nil it" do
    it "called refresh method" do
      YouTube.any_instance.should_receive(:refresh_auth_token).with(data["refresh"]) 
      YouTube.new(data["uid"], nil, data["refresh"])
    end
    it "refreshed the authentation token" do
      stub_request(:post, "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token")
            .with(:body => { "client_id"     => CLIENT_ID,
                        "client_secret" => CLIENT_SECRET,
                        "grant_type"=>"refresh_token",
                        "refresh_token" => data["refresh"], }
            ).to_return(:status => 200,
                        :body => File.read("#{$fixtures}/refresh_token.json"))
        yt = YouTube.new(data["uid"], nil, data["refresh"])
        yt.token.should == data["access_token"]
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems to me that using this stub

```
FooBar.stub(:foo).and_return("bar")
```

you are trying to stub nonexistent method.
Method `foo` is instance method but you stub class method.

If you would like to stub instance method FooBar#foo use `any_instance`

```
FooBar.any_instance.stub(:foo).and_return("bar")
```

**Update from comments**

Apply `stub` in `it` or `before` blocks.

new variant:

```
it 'place here some description for method foo' do
  FooBar.any_instance.stub(:foo).and_return("bar") 
  expect(FooBar.new.foo).to eql('bar')
end
```

or

```
# the order is important! 
describe "FooBar" do 
  before { FooBar.any_instance.stub(:foo).and_return("bar") } 
  subject { FooBar.new } 
  its(:foo) { should == "foo"} 
end
```

Comment: the place for stub confuse me. 
1. Stub should be placed in `it` block or in before block. 
2. it should be placed before the real method will be called.

make these changes and say if the exception is still there

Comment: about stub_request. Has your Gemfile gem `webmock`?

Comment: 1. I know. 2. I know. Yes it does. 3. Yes I have `webmock` in gemfile and installed.

Comment: Whoops, 1. fixed it all. Looks like I didn't know :)

Comment: if I understood you correctly you can test it in this way

    it 'place here some description for method foo' do
      FooBar.any_instance.stub(:foo).and_return("bar")
      expect(FooBar.new.foo).to eql('bar')
    end

or

    # the order is important!
    describe "FooBar" do
      before { FooBar.any_instance.stub(:foo).and_return("bar") }
      subject { FooBar.new }
      its(:foo) { should == "foo"}
    end

PS sorry I can't format code for pretty look :-/

Comment: Its OK, I understand everything now. I no longer have any issues. Thanks for teaching me.

Comment: Just update your answer so I can accept it as solution. Basically your second comment, point 1 is the answer.